# Why is my kernel image not upgraded?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, kylin

I'm using Ubuntu Kylin, when I type:

```
uname -r
```

I got:

```
3.16.0-53-generic
```

And in my /boot:

```
abi-3.16.0-52-generic     initrd.img-3.16.0-52-generic  System.map-3.16.0-53-generic
abi-3.16.0-53-generic     initrd.img-3.16.0-53-generic  System.map-3.16.0-55-generic
abi-3.16.0-55-generic     initrd.img-3.16.0-55-generic  System.map-3.16.0-56-generic
abi-3.16.0-56-generic     initrd.img-3.16.0-56-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-52-generic
config-3.16.0-52-generic  lost+found                    vmlinuz-3.16.0-53-generic
config-3.16.0-53-generic  memtest86+.bin                vmlinuz-3.16.0-55-generic
config-3.16.0-55-generic  memtest86+.elf                vmlinuz-3.16.0-56-generic
config-3.16.0-56-generic  memtest86+_multiboot.bin
grub                      System.map-3.16.0-52-generic
```

when I type `apt-get upgrade`, I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
linux-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic
linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

How can I get my Ubuntu upgraded to 3.16.0-56?
Why is it not automatically getting upgraded?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't upgrade by the normal command because Ubuntu is being cautious. If you upgrade using this command, some unnecessary dependencies will be removed and `sudo apt-get upgrade` doesn't upgrade by deleting anything.

To force the kernel upgrade, type the following:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see somewhere that this command possibly cause some problem. If i don't do this upgrade, will my system be updated in future in a safe way?

Comment: Well, first of all it doesn't, I do it all the time, as soon as a new kernel is released. But if you are being cautious then may wait for the next Ubuntu release and then update the kernel alongwith the OS.

Comment: @user4676257 basic answer should be yes, once newer kernel comes out you should be able to get it with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` . For the most users newer kernel doesn't bring much interest, so I wouldn't worry about that too much.  But if you insist , you could install newer driver manually. For instance , I have manually installed 4.1 kernel.  But really , I wouldn't worry about that too much

Comment: @Serg -  this is a doubt. If I don't upgrade it through `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` it doesn't upgrade to new kernel right. I am asking cause it never did in my case.

Comment: @Raphael It does upgrade to newer kernel  with regular `sudo apt-get upgrade`.  There should be a reason why it didn't upgrade. Perhaps you have an application that depends on that kernel ?

Comment: @Raphael is Ubuntu the only OS you have installed ?

Comment: No I dual boot with Windows 7 which I open once in 2 or 3 months.